# How to load a library's source-map with webpack

Tags: javascript, gulp, webpack

I'm building two project, one is a library for the other.
I'm using Gulp for building the library from TypeScript to ES5.
In my Gulpfile I use `gulp-sourcemaps` and it creates a source map file just next to my Javascript file plus a comment at the end of the file.

I use this library in my webpack project and I use source-map-loader in order to extract the data from the js files but I get this warning:

```
Cannot find SourceMap 'data:application/json;charset=utf8;base64,eyJ2ZXJza...
```

I wonder why webpack gives me this warning and what should I do for making it work in Chrome?

Comment: Is the TS code inlining the sourcemap into the files being transpiled? Otherwise, you could also try using ts-loader with webpack.

Comment: Thanks @SeanLarkin, but I'm using a Gulpfile to do the transpiling with gulp-sourcemaps. My TS code is not available to webpack since it's a npm library. I don't understand what I could do with ts-loader. I just want webpack to use the source map information which lies at the end of my JS files.